# natural norm functional analysis

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Show that $\|A\|=\sup\dfrac{\|Ax\|_{2}}{\|x\|_{1}}$ is compatible with $\|\cdot\|_{1}$ and  $\|\cdot\|_{2}$. This norm is often called the natural norm defined by $\|\cdot\|_{1}$ and  $\|\cdot\|_{2}$. If we choose $\|x\|_{1}=\max|a_{i}|$ and $\|y\|_{2}=\max|b_{j}|$, show that the natural norm is $\|A\|=\max \sum_{k=1}^{n}|\alpha_{jk}|$ .

My Solution:

If A norm is compatible then $\|Ax\|_{2}  \le \|A\|\cdot\|x\|_{1}$

$\|A\|=\sup\dfrac{\|Ax\|_{2}}{\|x\|_{1}} \le \sup\dfrac{\|A\|\cdot\|x\|_{1}}{\|x\|_{1}}=\sup\|A\|\ldots$ I don't know how proceed the solution help me please.

Comment: I don't think that's the definition of compatible. A matrix norm $$\|\cdot \|$$ is compatible with a vector norm $\|\cdot\|_a$ if $\|Ax\|_a\leq \|A\|\|x\|_a$

Comment: i took it from my book .

Comment: $\|x\|_{1}=\max|a_{i}|$ and $\|y\|_{2}=\max|b_{j}|$... what are $a_i$ and $b_j$???

Comment: coloumn and row